# FORTRAN and C interoperability - can REAL(4)s be too small?

Tags: c, interop, stack, fortran, stack-corruption

We've been having some weird crashes in some Intel FORTRAN code, and I eventually tracked the line down to:

```
L_F = EXP(-L_B2*L_BETASQ*L_DS)
```

Where the -L_B2*L_BETASQ*L_DS term evaluated to approximately -230.  As it happens, EXP(-230) evaluates to about 1e-100.  In all other known cases, L_DS is much smaller, resulting in the smallest (known) return from EXP being about 1e-50, which does not cause an error.

As soon as FORTRAN evaluates the clause EXP(-230), you get:

```
forrtl: severe (157): Program Exception - access violation
Image              PC        Routine            Line      Source
```

But no other information.

Exception 157 is generally concerned with interoperability, and you cannot debug into EXP in FORTRAN as it cannot find a particular .c file - which presumably means that EXP is implemented in C (which I find surprising).

My hypothesis is that FORTRAN has implemented EXP in C, but the interface cannot translate floats which are smaller than 1e-100 into REAL(4)s.  As I had previously believed floats and REAL(4)s to be byte-wise identical, I cannot back this hypothesis up - and I cannot find anything anywhere about it.

Before I close this bug down, can anyone confirm or deny my hypothesis - or provide me with another?

Best regards,

Mike

**EDIT:**  I'm going to mark this question as answered, as High Performance Mark has answered the immediate question.

My hypothesis is unfortunately incorrect - I've tried to trap the problem doing this:

```
L_ARG = L_B2*L_BETASQ*L_DS

IF (L_ARG .GT. 230.0) THEN
    L_F = 0.0
ELSE
    L_F = EXP(-L_ARG)
ENDIF
```

Unfortunately, the exception now (apparently) occurs in the L_ARG .GT. 230.0 clause.  This either means that the debugging in Release mode is worse than I thought, or it's some sort of 'stored up' floating point error (see ["Floating-point invalid operation" when inputting float to a stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515051/floating-point-invalid-operation-when-inputting-float-to-a-stringstream)).

Comment: I point to the 3rd paragraph of my answer. Switch on run-time array-bounds checking and compile-time procedure argument checking.

Comment: Debugging release code almost never works because of the register storage optimisation and the fact that the actual instructions that implement consecutive statements might get interspersed and thus the PC <-> source line relationship is completely broken.

Comment: Is your code 32-bit or 64-bit? If the code is 32-bit, is SSE math used? Because there are some differences in how underflows are handled in x87 and SSE. If your main program is written in Fortran, then try with the `/Qftz` option to `ifort`.

Comment: It's compiled 32-bit (but my own machine is 64-bit).  The main routine is in FORTRAN, but it dips in and out of C++ so often, it's untrue.  How do I find out which maths is being used?  I'm just about to experiment with the /Qftz option (it looks exactly what I need to change).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortran hasn't (necessarily) implemented anything in C. The implementation of standard intrinsics is compiler-specific; it is common to find that implementations call `libm` or one of its relatives.  From Intel's (or any other compiler writer's) point of view this makes sense, write one robust and fast implementation of `exp` in whatever language takes your fancy and call it from Fortran, C, Ada, COBOL, and all the other languages you've ever heard of.  It may even be sensible to write it in C.  Part of your hypothesis may, therefore, be correct.

However, unless you are explicitly writing C code and Fortran code and making a single binary from it there's not really any interoperability (in the Fortran standard sense) going on, all the dirty details of that are (or should be) hidden from you; the compiler ought to generate correct calls to whatever libraries it uses to implement `exp` and get the return values whatever they may be including `NaN`s and similar.

Certainly, the value of `exp(-230)` is `0.00000000` for a 4-byte real but I see no reason why a Fortran program which uses a library written in C should raise an access violation because it comes across those numbers.  I think it is far more likely that you have an error elsewhere in your program, perhaps trying to access an array element outside the bounds of the array, and that your run-time fails to identify it at the right location in the source code.  This is not uncommon.

**EDIT**

*I wrote this stuff about interoperability before (re-)reading the question.  Now that you've clarified that you are using interoperability features, it may be of interest or use ...*

You can certainly not depend on your Fortran's `real(4)` and your C's `float` being identical; it is very likely but not certain.  Most of the modern Fortran compilers (including Intel's) use kind type parameters which match the number of bytes in their representation, so the code `4` indicates that you are dealing with a 4-byte real which, on an IEEE-754 compliant processor, should be the same as a C `float`.  The Fortran standards do not require any correspondence between those kind type parameters and the number of bytes used to represent a number.  It's always worth checking your compiler documentation or doing some tests.

If you are concerned about interoperability you should probably be using Fortran's intrinsic features.  For example if you

```
use :: iso_c_binding
```

you have available a number of constants including `C_FLOAT` which can be used like this:

```
real(C_FLOAT) :: a_fortran_float
```

If your Fortran compiler supports this then `a_fortran_float` should match a C float on a *companion processor*.  This last term is left somewhat undefined, in practice compilers from the same stable seem always to be companions, for different stables sometimes yes sometimes no.  The Intel Fortran and C and C++ compilers seem to be companions in the required sense. It would not surprise me to learn that the Intel Fortran and MS C++ compilers do not play nicely together.

My vague recollections of C include an uncertainty that `float` is standardised, in which case you can't be sure, without testing or reading the documentation, that you really do have a 4-byte IEEE single-precision floating-point number on that side of your interoperation either.

Comment: Thanks, Mark - all interesting stuff.  The binary *is* actually a mixed FORTRAN-C++ binary, using VS2010 (so VC++ with Intel FORTRAN), but I hadn't thought that relevant to mention.  I can only step through the code in Release mode, as the problem doesn't get triggered in Debug mode, but in Release mode it is pretty adamant that it is the EXP call causing the problem.  The fact that this has been changed in our newer, working code also suggests (but doesn't prove) that it is EXP(-230) causing the problem.  I will try to produce an isolated example...